# Retornar o menor valor - Python

Tags: python, dicionário

```
from collections import OrderedDict #Pra poder acessar os elementos igual listas e tuplas.
                              v                 v                 v
lista_aberta = {(1,3): [1,2,3,4], (1,4): [2,3,4,9], (1,5): [3,4,1,7]}
```

Preciso verificar todos os elementos e retornar qual tem o [3] menor valor, que neste caso é o (1,3) onde o seu [3] valor equivale a 4.

uso uma estrutura de repetição pra comparar os valores, ou tem algum método mais direto pra fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desconheço qualquer "método direto" pronto para isto, a não ser que você mesmo a desenvolva obviamente.

Em todo caso, usaria algo semelhante a isso, criando um método para reutilização e assim utilizando um "método direto".
Utilizando o `sys.maxsize`(para **python2** utilize `sys.maxint`) para garantir que sempre pegue o menor valor já que está usando o maior valor inteiro para comparar inicialmente e acessando com laço de repetição a sua escolha(utilizei o `for` para ficar mais claro o que está ocorrendo).

```
import sys

lista_aberta = {(1,3): [1,2,3,4], (1,4): [2,3,4,9], (1,5): [3,4,1,7]}

menor: int = sys.maxsize
objMenor = {}
for key in lista_aberta:
    if lista_aberta[key][3] < menor:
        menor = lista_aberta[key][3]
        objMenor = {key : lista_aberta[key]}

print('Menor valor da lista é: ', menor, 'Obj ->', objMenor)
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito.